# Invalid value at 'requests[0].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32)

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google spreadsheets API v4. I want to delete some rows via python script. i tried their example code and i got the following error

> Invalid value at 'requests[0].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32)

**my code:**

```
    batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "ROWS",
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 3
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 1,
                    "endIndex": 4
                }
            }
        },
    ],
}

request = sheets_service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=sheetId, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
response = request.execute()
```

**The full traceback**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/yahia/DSP_Project_Server_Software/python_scripts/TMSA/TMSA.py", line 70, in 
>       main()
>     File "/home/yahia/DSP_Project_Server_Software/python_scripts/TMSA/TMSA.py", line 67, in main
>       response = request.execute()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
>   googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/sheetId:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[0].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "sheetId"
>   Invalid value at 'requests[1].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "sheetId"">

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your script, `sheetId` is used for `"sheetId": sheetId,` and `spreadsheetId=sheetId`.

1. `sheetId` at `"sheetId": sheetId,` is `gid` of URL. Please check here. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id
2. `sheetId` at `spreadsheetId=sheetId` is Spreadsheet ID. Please check here. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id

Each `sheetId` is different. So please modify them.