# Add a Protected Range to an existing NamedRange

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I have an existing worksheet with an existing `NamedRange` for it and I would like to call the `batch_update` method of the API to protect that range from being edited by anyone other than the user that makes the [`batch_update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) call.

I have seen an example on how to [add protected ranges via a new range definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620930/invalid-value-at-requests0-delete-dimension-range-sheet-id-type-int32), but not from an existing `NamedRange`.

I know I need to send the [addProtectedRangeResponse](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/response#addprotectedrangeresponse) request. Can I define the request body with a `Sheetname!NamedRange` notation?

```
this_range = worksheet_name + "!" + nrange
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    'requests': [
        {
            "addProtectedRange": {
                "protectedRange": {
                "range": {
                    "name": this_range,
                },
                    "description": "Protecting xyz",
                    "warningOnly": False
                }
            }
        }
    ],  
}
```

EDIT: Given @Tanaike feedback, I adapted the call to something like:

```
        body = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "addProtectedRange": {
                        "protectedRange": {
                            "namedRangeId": namedRangeId,
                            "description": "Protecting via gsheets_manager",
                            "warningOnly": False,
                            "requestingUserCanEdit": False
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        res2 = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ssId, body=body).execute()
        print(res2)
```

But although it lists the new protections, it still lists 5 different users (all of them) as editors. If I try to manually edit the protection added by my gsheets_manager script, it complains that the range is invalid:

[image]

Interestingly, it seems to ignore the requestUserCanEdit flag according to the returning message:

`{u'spreadsheetId': u'NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN', u'replies': [{u'addProtectedRange': {u'protectedRange': {u'requestingUserCanEdit': True, u'description': u'Protecting via gsheets_manager', u'namedRangeId': u'1793914032', u'editors': {}, u'protectedRangeId': 2012740267, u'range': {u'endColumnIndex': 1, u'sheetId': 1196959832, u'startColumnIndex': 0}}}}]}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `namedRangeId` for your situation? The flow of the sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve `namedRangeId` using `spreadsheets().get` of Sheets API.
2. Set a protected range using `namedRangeId` using `spreadsheets().batchUpdate` of Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

```
nrange = "### name ###"
ssId = "### spreadsheetId ###"

res1 = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=ssId, fields="namedRanges").execute()
namedRangeId = ""
for e in res1['namedRanges']:
    if e['name'] == nrange:
        namedRangeId = e['namedRangeId']
        break
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addProtectedRange": {
                "protectedRange": {
                    "namedRangeId": namedRangeId,
                    "description": "Protecting xyz",
                    "warningOnly": False
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
res2 = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ssId, body=body).execute()
print(res2)
```

#### Note:

- This script supposes that Sheets API can be used for your environment.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it to your situation.

#### References:

- [ProtectedRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#ProtectedRange)
- [Named and Protected Ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/ranges)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit:

In my above answer, I modified your script using your settings. If you want to protect the named range, please modify `body` as follows.

Modified `body`

```
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addProtectedRange": {
                "protectedRange": {
                    "namedRangeId": namedRangeId,
                    "description": "Protecting xyz",
                    "warningOnly": False,
                    "editors": {"users": ["### your email address ###"]}, # Added
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

By this, the named range can be modified by only you. I'm using such settings and I confirm that it works in my environment. But if in your situation, this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: I successfully ran the code with your code snippet, and it returns something like in the edited version of my question above. I can see the new protections in the Protected Sheets & ranges in the website view, but the ones added programmatically still let everyone edit the document, listing 5 users as editors. Any ideas? Maybe there is a flag missing?

Comment: @719016 that sounds like a different question

Comment: The protection does not protect the worksheet range from being edited by all 5 users, so in essence it's still about how to successfully apply the protection.

Comment: @719016 Thank you for replying. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience and my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your support.

Comment: @719016 no, the original question was "how do i apply protection to a named range (instead of a normal range)". Now you moved the goal posts and are now seeking the answer to "allow only one editor to modify a protected range". Notice how one is about NamedRange -> ProtectedRange and the other only about configuring the ProtectedRange's properties? You could have had 2 perfectly great questions, but you've insisted on muddling both into a single one.

Comment: @719016 Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @719016 Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it.

Comment: It now works as per the answer in @Tanaike post. The addition of the email addresses made all the difference. Thanks very much for you help!

Comment: @719016 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.