# Is it possible to delete created spread sheet via api, i mean if we can create an spread sheet there should be an option to delete it

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

### Delete complete sheet with google API using python

I created spread sheets via python now I am looking to delete these spread sheets via 'spread sheet id' 
I think code is irrelevant it was a hit and try effort all I am looking is **to delete created spread sheet via python code**

I have seen in the documentation  [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet)! on how to delete a sheet I didn't get python code so I tried the following code 
I found the sample python code for batch_update from   [a link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/sheets/snippets/spreadsheet_snippets.py)

```py
body = {
    'requests': [
                   {
        "deleteSheet": {
                      "sheetId": spreadsheet_id
                 }
                   }
                ]
     }
     response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
          spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
         body=body).execute()
```

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1b_kJP24tVfTr9LgJIw_i_FqlFDWzCsvYmIJ6TP1_bqU:batchUpdate?alt=json
>
> > returned "Invalid value at 'requests[0].delete_sheet.sheet_id' 
> >     (TYPE_INT32), "1b_kJP24tVfTr9LgJIw_i_FqlFDWzCsvYmIJ6TP1_bqU"">

Comment: This is a wrong question i think i misunderstood sheet_id as spread sheet id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620930/invalid-value-at-requests0-delete-dimension-range-sheet-id-type-int32

Comment: With the help of the StackOverflow community, I may have found a possible resolution that I also need to integrate with google drive also, only integration with google spreadsheet will not let you delete the files, it is still surprising for me but also somewhat make sense

Answer (score 1):

according to [Google sheets api documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet),

Try changing `deletesheet` to `deleteSheet` and `sheetid` to `sheetId`

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteSheet": {
        "sheetId": spreadsheet_id
      }
    }
  ]
}
```